# Polygon Problem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms

There are $N$ regions which are numbered from $1$ to $N$. Each region is represented by a single simple polygon on the 2D plane. Simple polygon means the boundary of the polygon does not cross itself. You should not confuse simple polygon with convex polygon. There are no two regions share a common point.

Now given $Q$ queries,I have to find the polygon that contain a specific point. Note that a point on the boundary of the polygon is considered to be inside the polygon.

Now ,suppose if we have $N=2$ which can be as large as $10^6$ in input.and suppose the two regions coordinates are given as follow:-

Region 1 : $4$ (show number of coordinates pair)

$(1,4),(1,7),(7,7),(7,4)$

Region 2 : $3$

$(1,1),(5,3),(7,1)$

Now ,suppose we have $3$ queries :

$(2,3),(3,6),(6,2)$

We can clearly see first one is not in any of the regions second is in first region and third is in third region.

How to solve this problem if I have large number of queries of order $10^6$ and provided that $3 ≤$ total coordinate pairs for each polygon $≤ 300,000$ and all coordinates are non-negative integer which do not exceed $10^9$.

Comment: Smells like a Project Euler problem.

Comment: Which problem..?Tell me plz...

Comment: I didn't have a specific one in mind. I meant, it smells like the kind of problem that they use at Project Euler, especially with your request for computer code.

Comment: K..Sory,but its not from Project Euler

Comment: Good. Where is it from, then?

Comment: I just read it from net. And tried to solve it.

Comment: From the net? URL, please?

Comment: Dont ask from where the question is..from where ever it is we should try to tackle it.

Comment: Flagging to close: the comments show the OP got this problem from somewhere and refuses to divulge the source. This is a dangerous precedent. I'm sure none of us want to be responsible for MO being used to cheat.

Comment: @DavidWhite: I must admit that I was oblivious to this possibility. In any case, I hope I get at least an *A-*. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most practical method is to partition your polygon into trapezoids, and use
Seidel's randomized point location algorithm:

   [image: Trapezoid Decomp]
There is a high-level description [in Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Trapezoidal_decomposition).
You can find more detailed explanations in many locations, including
Section 7.11.4 of *[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html)*. And Seidel's original paper is quite readable:

> Seidel, Raimund. "A simple and fast incremental randomized algorithm for computing trapezoidal decompositions and for triangulating polygons." *Computational Geometry* 1.1 (1991): 51-64. ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925772191900124))

From the *Abstract*:

> "As a by-product our algorithm creates a search structure of expected linear size that allows point location queries in the resulting trapezoidation in logarithmic expected time."

(*Added*.) You may find a working [Java applet here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2002/JukkaKaartinen/).

Comment: Is it applicable to polygons in 2D..?

Comment: Yes, 2D. That's what you specified in your question.

Comment: K...What is its time complexity(in terms of big Oh notations to check for particular point).?

Comment: $O(\log n)$, for a total of $n$ vertices. I added a quote from the abstract.

Comment: K...And what about space complexity..?Because such large number of vertices are not easy to store..

Comment: As the abstract says, "expected linear size," i.e., $O(n)$. You couldn't hope for more.

Comment: Ya..You are right.thanx for help.Can i get its implementation in c/c++/java.thanx in advance

Comment: hackerrrr: after this very helpful and detailed reply from Joseph O'Rourke, you might consider officially accepting it as the answer to your question. You should see a check mark next to his answer that you can click. Please note that the MO software will periodically recycle questions with unaccepted answers to the front page, which we don't want. (Also, 2 points are added to your reputation each time you officially accept an answer.)